# Handsontable datepicker week number modification

Tags: datepicker, handsontable, week-number, pickadate

Hello i am using the Handsontable library and i have a problem.
I cant find anyway to configure the date Picker to start counting after the first Thursday of the year.
As a result i get a week more than i should.

I get week 27 instead of week 26 for 29-06-2016.

Anyone has a suggestion?

Comment: Maybe check the [docs](https://docs.handsontable.com/pro/1.5.0/demo-date.html) regarding the custom datepicker options you can provide? I know you can set several options including `firstDay`, `showWeekNumber`, etc.

Comment: I checked the docs and also the docs for the Pikaday which is the base for the date picker but no luck for my problem.

Comment: Hmm. Can you explain a bit more what you mean by "start counting after the first Thursday of the year"?

Comment: I guess the description is not the best.Sorry for that.What i actually mean is that i want to start counting the first week the first week after the first thursday of the year.

Answer (score 0):

You will use the ISO 8601 format. In Pickaday you have to set the option "showWeekNumber" to "true". The default is "false"